# Trying to use keyboard to move focus from one anchor tag to another with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, focus, anchor

So trying to make large website (which I cannot redesign) ADA compliant and came across an issue. Need to traverse the focus from one anchor to another further down the page when the first anchor is activated by keyboard.

Made a little dummy project to experiment ([Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaitan/s7vobpaw/)).

---

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js.txt"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Page</h1>
    <p>content.</p>
    <a href="#" onclick="jump('b3')" id="b1">b1</a>
    <a href="#">b2</a>
    <a href="#"id="b3">b3</a>
    <button onclick="jump('b1')" id="b4">b4</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js.txt:

```
function jump(id){
   test = document.getElementById(id);
   test.focus();
}
```

---

If I click on b1, it will change focus to b3 as expected. Same with b4 to b1. Using keyboard to press space or enter on the b4 button will change focus to b1.

But, if I try to use the keyboard (enter key) to have b1 change the focus to b3, b3 flickers and focus reverts to b1. Placing break points in the js, shows the js being activated (hence the flicker), but the focus doesnt stay on b3.

---

To explain the situation, we have a header full of navigation. For some reason, several pseudo drop down menus exist on the header (they actually make things visible that were hidden) and they are opened by clicking the anchor tags that make up the header. The contents of the drop down are all anchor tags and are NOT children of the top menu

I need to be able to activate the menu items and have the drop down window appear. After which the focus should jump within the window rather than progressing to the next menu item.

Finally, after I have traversed the contents, I need to return to the top most menu which is an anchor tag.

---

Thank you to everyone for your help solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `tabindex`? That's what it is for.

If you want to jump around in the page with clicks, use named anchors, that's what they're for.

Comment: Two issues with this from what I understand (New to ADA). 



1. either I make everything but the focused element element index of -1 which I cant do due to how large the site is and how inflexible things are.

2. Or I have to number everything which leads to a nightmare for maintenance further down the line

Comment: Use tabindex values that leave room for insertion: 1, 100, 200... It's the best you can do. This still remains an "unsolved" issue in HTML.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

Comment: added some further context to my initial post